# how to store a regex-capture-group as a variable in vim script?

Tags: regex, vim, capture-group

i'm trying to write a vimscript to refactor some legacy code.

roughly i have a lot of files in this format

```
$this['foo'] = array();
{
    $this['foo']['id'] = 123;
    $this['foo']['name'] = 'name here';
    $this['foo']['name2'] = 'name here2';
    $this['foo']['name3'] = 'name here3';
}
```

I want to reformat this into

```
$this['foo'] = array(
    'id' => 123;
    'name' 'name here';
    'name2' 'name here';
    'name3' 'name here';
);
```

where foo is variable.

I'm trying to match

```
$this['foo'] = array()
{
```

with this regex

```
/\zs\$this\[.*\]\ze = array()\_s{;
```

so i can execute this code

```
# move cursor down two lines, visual select the contents of the block { }
jjvi{

# use variable, parent_array to replace 
s/\= parent_array . '\[\([^=]\+\)] = \(.*\);'/'\1' => \2,
```

but of course i need to let parent_array = /\zs$this[(.*)]\ze = array(); which isnt the right syntax apparently...

TL;DR

```
function Refactor()

    # what is the proper syntax to do this assignment ?
    let parent_array = /\zs\$this\[.*\]\ze = array()\_s{;

    if (parent_array)
        jjvi{
        '<,'>s/\= parent_array . '\[\([^=]\+\)] = \(.*\);'/'\1' => \2,
    endif

endfunction
```

EDIT* fixed escaping as per commenter FDinoff

Comment: You also need to escape `$`, `[` and `]` in parent_array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there's only one such match in a line, and you want the first such line:

```
let pattern = '\$this\[.*\]\ze = array()\_s{;'
if search(pattern, 'cW') > 0
    let parent_array = matchstr(getline('.'), pattern)
endif
```

This first locates the next matching line, then extracts the matching text. Note that this moves the cursor, but with the `'n'` flag to `search()`, this can be avoided.